# right drupal sql query

Tags: database

what is the right sql query for drupal 7 if the query like this

```
SELECT MAX(nopeserta) 
FROM `1_jp_peserta` 
WHERE jpke=$q1 AND lomba=$q2 AND kelamin=$q3
```

i have tried in drupal like this

```
$q4 = db_query("SELECT MAX(nopeserta) AS nopeserta FROM {1_jp_peserta} 
WHERE jpke=:q1 AND lomba=:q2 AND kelamin=:q3",
array(':q1'=>'$q1',':q2'=>'$q2',':q3'=>'$q3'))->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

but the result is

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters 
were bound in jpeserta_form_submit()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `db_query()` the query is executed for you, I think the error you're getting is because you're re-running `execute()` on it. Also it looks like you're trying to interpolate variables into a string using single quotes, when you need to use double quotes (or none at all in your case).

Try this:

```
$q4 = db_query("
  SELECT MAX(nopeserta) AS nopeserta FROM {1_jp_peserta} WHERE jpke=:q1 AND lomba=:q2 AND kelamin=:q3", array(':q1'=>$q1,':q2'=>$q2,':q3'=>$q3))->fetchAssoc();
```